# Extract a list of Element in SQL with a Regex

Tags: python, sql, regex

I'm trying to extract tables names, after a FROM clause, from an SQL query using Regex, but without any satisfying result.

What i'd like to accomplish is to extract:

`table_1, table_2, table_3` both before and after a JOIN clause, discarding any other "name" or token.

The **goal** is to find which "tables dependencies" the query has.

Here an example:

```
SELECT ("total") "_charges"
FROM
  table_1
, table_2
, table_3 table_3_alias
WHERE ("table_1"."id" = "table_2"."id");
```

I'd like to get: `table_1 table_2 table_3`

```
SELECT *
FROM
  table_1
, table_2
, table_3 table_3_alias JOIN table4, table5_abc
WHERE table_1.id > 12;
```

I'd like to get: `table_1 table_2 table_3 table4 table5_abc`

The SQL is just made up and is not significant by itself, however it represents the possible cases I saw in my tests: table names with underscores, commas next to the word or after the words separated by a number of white spaces, new lines etc..

My best try is:

`(?!\W+from_)(\W+FROM\W*(?!select|where)(\w*)|JOIN\W*(?!select)(?!.*array)(\w*))`

which gets only the first element of the two lists, table_1 and table4 in a capturing group.

I'd appreciate a lot of anyone with great Regex knowledge could help on this!

Comment: Please add the rdbms system you are targeting. You might wish to invest more thought/research in the nature of sql queries you may encounter and which information to extract from them (or, if having done that, be more specific about it in the question). Table names may also occur in subqueries (which in turn may occur in the projection part of the query ie. the `select`section) and common table expressions. If there is any context from which you do _not_ want to get table names, regexen are likely the wrong tool as you would have to employ them to partly simulate sql parsing.

Comment: the RDBMS is MySQL, and yes i'm aware of subqueries, nesting etc. I had a look as well to a LL(1) parser to tokenize the SQL but it gets really complicated. I wanted to use Regex to hopefully cover 90% of the cases.

I'm open on suggestions on any parsing technology that i'm not aware of.

Thank you!

Comment: Sugqesting a different approach, try to identify _uses_ of table names/aliases by looking for the patterns `"?[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*"?[.]`  and `"?[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*"? "?[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*"?` for prospective alias definitions. You'd need a postprocessing step to resolve table aliases to actual table names, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried your approach however it looks a bit different from what i'm trying to accomplish. I made and edit to the orginal question to be more specific.

My goal is to identify/extract dependencies of an SQL query (therefore the list table_1 etc) usages are not the best way to identify the table dependencies as a table can be listed in a FROM clause but not used (as crazy it sounds, it might happen).

Would be great just to find a way to iterate this part `(\W+FROM\W*(?!select|where)(\w*)` over a comma separated list of values in regex